# How to use the Join class in Weka APIs?

Tags: java, join, weka

I need to join two csv files that I'm loading into my program, but I really can't understand how to do it with Weka APIs. I figured out that I should be using the [Join](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/knowledgeflow/steps/Join.html) class, however I can't understand how it should be used and I'm unable to find any kind of example on the whole internet. Any help?

Comment: Are you trying to join them side-by-side or one-after-the-other?

Comment: @fracpete If by side-by-side you mean relational database style join, and by one-after-the other you mean appending the tuples of one file to the other, I need to do a side-by-side join.

Answer (score 0):

For merging datasets (i.e., placing them side-by-side), you can use the `mergeInstances` method of the [weka.core.Instances](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/core/Instances.html#mergeInstances-weka.core.Instances-weka.core.Instances-) class.

The `weka.core.Instances` class also allows you to do that from the [commandline](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/core/Instances.html#main-java.lang.String:A-).